# Sphinx PDF output using latexpdf

Tags: pdf, python-3.x, latex, python-sphinx

I am trying to build Sphinx doc output as PDF rather than HTML. I can only use the tools which come with Sphinx, i.e. I cannot download additionl tools like rst2pdf. I have tried using 'make latexpdf', per the Sphinx documentation, which states it will produce pdf in addition to the .tex files. However I am only getting .tex. What am I missing? The Sphinx documentation states that PDF files will be produced.

Comment: Do you have LaTeX installed?

Comment: That would probably be the solution!  I know it probably sounds dumb, but i didn't realize that was a requirement.  I thought that Sphinx actually did the writing, not a call to LaTeX.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Sphinx** uses **Latex** to export the documentation as a PDF file.
Thus one needs the basic Latex dependencies used to write a pdf on the system.

For example, on a system running Ubuntu 16.04, they can be downloaded and installed by :

> **`apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended`**
>
> <sub>If running Sphinx 1.6 or above on GNU/Linux or OSX, you may also need the **`latexmk`** package.
>
>   **Reference: [sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/builders.html#sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder) documentation.**</sub>

After installing the above packages, running  `make latexpdf` in the sphinx project directory generates the documentation output as the PDF file `./_build/latex/<sphinx-project-name>.pdf>`

---

<sub>**Note:** In the current scenario where you do not see a PDF file on your system after running `make latexpdf`, check the output of the command for any errors regarding missing latex tools/files. Use the system package manager to identify the missing packages and install them.</sub>

Comment: Sphinx 1.6 will add the [latexmk requirement](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/builders.html#sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder)